# Is it true that for $t\in[0,1/2]$ and $x\in[t,1-t]$ we have $f(x)\geq f(t)$ if $X$ is single peaked left-skewed with support $[0,1]$

Tags: density-function, skewness

From the typical plots of single peaked and left skewed distributions, I am guessing the statement is true. But is it possible to prove it formally or give a counter example?

Comment: The truth of this statement depends on what you mean by "left-skewed": please give us the definition you have in mind.  When you do that, tell us how $f$ is connected with $X$.  Are you perhaps assuming $X$ is a *continuous* random variable with PDF $f$?

Comment: @whuber, I am thinking about a continuous variable with pdf $f(x)$. And it is funny that now I find that I don't have a clear definition for skewness because I have never learned an exact definition. I check wiki and I am guessing what I mean is the Pearson's moment coefficient of skewness.

Comment: Whatever your definition might be, I think you might get considerable insight by considering triangular distributions where $f$ is zero until $x=a \ge 0$, rises linearly to a peak at $x=b$, drops linearly back to zero at $x=c\le 1$, and then remains zero.  By making $b-a\gt c-b$ you get a unimodal left-skewed distribution.  But by shifting $a, b, c$ around you can explore the comparisons between $f(x)$ and $f(t)$.

Comment: @whuber, is it possible to give some conditions to ensure the statement is true? You mentioned the truth of the statement depends on the definition of "left skewed". Is there such a definition?

Comment: I think you would have to make your statement a tautology by defining "left-skewed" in just this way.  Unfortunately, that definition would not have much to do with the usual meanings of "skewed," primarily because it hinges fundamentally on an asymmetry with respect to the value $1/2$.  If you were (a) to remove the restriction that the support of $X$ be in $[0,1]$ and (b) to change the condition to "there exists $a$ such that $f(x)\gt f(a-t)$ for all $t\gt 0$ and $|x-a|\lt t$" then your criterion could plausibly taken as having some meaning with respect to the intuitive idea of skewness.